# How can a custom snapshot location be used?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I use `stack` Haskell tool. It caches compiled packages in snapshot folders like:

```
Users
  +-- ...
  +-- Its_Me
        +-- ...
        +-- .stack
               +-- ...
               +-- snapshots
                     +-- aarch64-osx
                     |    +-- ...
                     +-- x86_64-osx   
                           +-- ...
                           +-- b673acf89...    <== my project uses this
```

So, is there a way to tell a `stack` to use not `/Users/Its_Me/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/b673acf89...` but, for example, `/Users/Its_Me/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/I_WANT_HERE` ?

Because it only comes to my mind to change the whole stack root to be honest...

PS. By the way, this hash - `b673acf89...` - it is a hash of what exactly?

Comment: I'd consider the exact contents of the `.stack` directory to be an internal detail, possibly subject to change from one version of `stack` to the other, hence not something one should rely on. Why do you care about which names `stack` uses for its internal data?

Comment: I hit a weird problem when I had cached there "wrong" dylib file (without dyld load commands inside it, no idea how it happens). And I share this machine, so I decided to find a way to use own snapshot folder for my project.

Answer (score 1):

As I read stack's documentation, they don't mention how the snapshot folder is organized, nor provide any options to directly influence it. Therefore I would assume it's an internal logic, and I wouldn't rely on it in a longer term.

The closest you can get to having an isolated snapshot directory would be to [provide a custom snapshot](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/), but that doesn't give you any control over the folder directory.